# COUNT two text values using LIKE - mysql

Tags: mysql

So I am trying to count the number of cities in my database that begins with Z and A in one query. From a few Googling searches, I came up with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE city WHEN 'Z%' then 1 else null end) as count_Z,
       COUNT(CASE city WHEN 'A%' then 1 else null end) as count_A
FROM city
WHERE city LIKE 'Z%' AND 'A%';
```

However, I am not getting any returns when I should have 19 rows returned for Z and 43 rows returned for A.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I tried adding two likes and using OR but i still get 0 rows returned for both values.

Comment: So is there  a way to count two text values in one query?

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are able to use the following form `Z%` in your case statement. One way to achive this would be to use `SUM()` instead of case:

```
SELECT SUM(name LIKE 'A%') countA, 
       SUM(name LIKE 'Z%') countZ     
FROM city;
```

Note that you must use two individual `LIKE` statements when you check against two values. Consider the following table:

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | AAA  |
|    2 | ZZZ  |
|    3 | AAB  |
|    4 | ZZA  |
+------+------+
```

The following query:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> 
WHERE name LIKE 'A%' OR 'Z%';
```

Would return:

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | AAA  |
|    3 | AAB  |
+------+------+
```

Since you must use `city LIKE 'A%' OR city LIKE 'Z%'` for this to work as expected ie using two distinctive like statements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the last line should be:

`WHERE city LIKE 'Z%' OR city LIKE 'A%'`

... Last time I checked it's not possible for a name to start with *both* Z and A.

Comment: He must have two `LIKE` statements for this to work.